# undefined variable php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, yii

en este caso se trata de obtener un archivo xls para obtener un informe de ventas en el cual establezco primero el header que son los títulos de las columnas y después con una función vuelco toda la búsqueda en filas. Al descargar el xls estoy obteniendo error en la linea 61 en la que dice que la variable $data no esta definida y también en la función que llamo pasando tres parámetros entre ellos $data En el código la tengo definida en la linea 8, estaría muy agradecido por su ayuda gracias. Estoy realizando una actualización de la web

```
     case 'rptAdminSalesMerchant':
                if ($res=$db_ext->rst($stmt)){              
                        foreach ($res as $val) {                                
                            $date=prettyDate($val['date_created'],true);
                            $date=Yii::app()->functions->translateDate($date);
                            
                            $item=FunctionsV3::translateFoodItemByOrderId($val['order_id']);
                            $data[]=array();
                            //get notes by order_id in mt_order_history
                            $notes_query = "SELECT * FROM
                                {{order_history}}
                                WHERE
                                order_id=".$val['order_id']." AND status='note'
                                LIMIT 0,1
                                ";
                            $notes = "";
                            if ( $notes_res=$this->rst($notes_query)){
                                $notes = $notes_res[0]['notes'];
                            }

                            //get driver first name  in mt_driver by order_id join mt_driver_task
                            $task_id_query = "SELECT * FROM {{driver_task}} WHERE order_id=".$val['order_id']." LIMIT 0,1";
                            if ($driver_res=$this->rst($task_id_query)){
                                $driver_id = $driver_res[0]['driver_id'];
                                $task_id = $driver_res[0]['task_id'];
                            }
                            $driver_name = "";
                            if($driver_id != null) {
                                $driver_name_query = "SELECT * FROM
                                  {{driver}}  
                                  WHERE 
                                  driver_id=" . $driver_id . "
                                LIMIT 0,1
                                ";
                                if ($driver_name_res = $this->rst($driver_name_query)) {
                                    $driver_name = $driver_name_res[0]['first_name'];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                $driver_name = "";

                            if($task_id != null){
                                //get in mt_driver_task_photo by order_id join mt_driver_task
                                $task_photo_query = "SELECT * FROM
                                      {{driver_task_photo}}  
                                      WHERE 
                                      task_id=".$task_id."
                                    LIMIT 0,1
                                    ";
                                $photo_name = "";
                                if ( $task_photo_res=$this->rst($task_photo_query)){
                                    if($task_photo_res[0]['photo_name'] == "")
                                        $photo_name = "";
                                    else
                                        $photo_name = "https:*******".$task_photo_res[0]['photo_name'];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                $photo_name = "";

                            $data[]=array(
                                $val['order_id'],
                                  stripslashes($val['restaurant_name']),
                                  ucwords($val['client_name']),
                                  $val['contact_phone'],
                                  $item,
                                  ucwords(Yii::t("default",$val['trans_type'])),
                                  strtoupper(Yii::t("default",$val['payment_type'])),
                                  standardPrettyFormat($val['sub_total'],$merchant_id),
                                  standardPrettyFormat($val['tax'],$merchant_id),
                                  standardPrettyFormat($val['total_w_tax'],$merchant_id),
                                  ucwords($val['status']),
                                  ucwords($val['request_from']),
                                  $date,
                                  $val['delivery_charge'],
                                  $val['voucher_amount'],
                                  $val['points_discount'],
                                  $val['cart_tip_value'],
                                  $notes,
                                  $photo_name,
                                  $driver_name,
                            );
                        
                        }                       
                    }               
                    
                    $header=array(
                    Yii::t("default","Ref#"),
                    Yii::t("default","Merchant Name"),
                    Yii::t("default","Name"),
                    Yii::t("default","Contact#"),
                    Yii::t("default","Item"),
                    Yii::t("default","TransType"),
                    Yii::t("default","Payment Type"),
                    Yii::t("default","Total"),                      
                    Yii::t("default","Tax"),
                    Yii::t("default","Total W/Tax"),
                    Yii::t("default","Status"),
                    Yii::t("default","Platform"),
                    Yii::t("default","Date"),
                    Yii::t("default","Delivery Charge"),
                    Yii::t("default","Voucher Amount"),
                    Yii::t("default","Points Discount"),
                    Yii::t("default","Tips"),
                    Yii::t("default","Notes"),
                    Yii::t("default","Picture"),
                    Yii::t("default","Driver Name")
                    );
                    
                    $filename = $this->data['rpt'].'-'. date('c') .'.xls';
                    ExcelExporter::sendAsXLS($data, $filename, $header);
                    exit; 
                    break;
```

Muchas gracias por todo

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no hay referencias anteriores a $data antes de esta llamada

```
$data[]=array();
```

Va a generar un error ya que se espera que $data ya este creado y sea un array.
Segun lo que veo del codigo, se espera que data sea un array de filas de datos. Por ello debes inicializarlo en algun punto, podria ser al principio del `case` :

```
case 'rptAdminSalesMerchant':
    $data=array();
    if (...)
```

Luego mas adelante tambien se usa este array para agregar un elemento, por lo que el problema se solucionara para ambos casos.